# How do I use multiple schema GenerationProviders

Tags: json.net

We are using Json.Net Schema and require multiple generation providers.
However when we specify more than one generation provider it seems that only the last one in the list is used.

Here is an example where only ObjectNotNullableGenerationProvider is used and StringEnumGeneration is ignored.

Any example of example of multiple providers or help on why this is not working would be appreciated.

Example:

```
var generator = new JSchemaGenerator
    {
        SchemaReferenceHandling = SchemaReferenceHandling.None,
        DefaultRequired = Required.Default,
    };

generator.GenerationProviders.Add(new StringEnumGenerationProvider());
generator.GenerationProviders.Add(new ObjectNotNullableGenerationProvider());

var jsonSchema = generator.Generate(typeof(SchemaTest));
```

Answer (score 0):

The [GetSchema](http://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Schema_Generation_JSchemaGenerationProvider_GetSchema.htm) method on `JSchemaGenerationProvider` returns a new schema. Only the first matching schema generation provider is called and its schema is used.

What you could do is take the source code from `StringEnumGenerationProvider` (available [here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/Generation/StringEnumGenerationProvider.cs)) and have you own version that either inherits from `ObjectNotNullableGenerationProvider` or reuses its logic internally.